# try catch no alert box android

Tags: android, exception, try-catch

I am trying to show a alert box in my app when numberformat exception occurs but for some reason the app crashes

add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {

                preRes = new Double(field1.getText().toString());
                lastCommand = "+";
                field1.setText("");
                count = 0;

            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {    


                show = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)
                .setTitle("Error")
                .setMessage("no inputs").setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();

            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: how do i get the stack trace on android using eclipse

Comment: type `adb logcat` into a command prompt window.  Make sure `adb` is in your Environment Variables or run the command from the proper folder.

Comment: a null pointer exception has been occurred every single time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have to create the Builder before you can begin setting properties.  Try something like this (Assuming `show` is an AlertDialog):

```
show = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).create();
show.setTitle("Error")
  .setMessage("no inputs")
  .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
  .show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You miss following after creating your `AlertDialog.Builder`

```
AlertDialog alert = show .create();
 alert.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a Null Pointer, try using `new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())..` or `new AlertDialog.Builder(this)..`.  You might have missed initialing the `mContext` field.

If that doesn't work, try

```
show = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)
            .setTitle("Error")
            .setMessage("no inputs").setPositiveButton("OK", 
new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        captureImage();
    }
}
).show();
```

Comment: adb logcat gives you the log from the Android OS and the apps running.  When an app crashes/Force Closes, it spits out the Java Stack Trace.  That stack trace is required for proper debugging.

Comment: cmd just generates something on the screen which is not readable.. wht should be the output of that command ex a text file or something like it where the stack trace could be read

Comment: Did you try using the code from my update?  If the context isn't null, then try putting a listener in beside "OK" rather than null.  The code is all there.

Comment: I did try but i get a error on captureImage method it says its undefined.. why can't i use this instead of mContext

Answer (score 0):

Likely an unchecked exception other than `NumberFormatException` is being thrown, for example `NullPointerException`.

A NPE could be thrown if either `field1` or `mContext` are not properly initialized.

Regardless, you need to get logcat working so you can debug the problem. The stacktrace will point you to where the error is occuring.

To open logcat in Eclipse, go to Window > Show View > Other... and select the logcat view.

Alternatively you can access the logcat view from Window > Open Perspective > Other... and select the DDMS perspective.